# In html, how to get row data on button in which button is present?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, row

I am trying to get data from a table on button click for that row in which the clicked button is present.

Here is my html table:

```
<table class="table" id="eduEditTbl">
    <tr>
        <td class="hidden-phone hidden-tablet hidden-desktop"></td>
        <td class="span3 hidden-phone"> Degree </td>
        <td class="span3 hidden-phone"> College </td>
        <td class="span3 hidden-phone"> Year </td>                                          
        <td class="span3 hidden-phone"> Country </td>                                           
        <td class="span3 hidden-phone"> Action </td>
    </tr>                                       
    <tr class="eduEditRow">
        <td class="hidden-phone hidden-tablet hidden-desktop ids">1</td>
        <td class="span3 hidden-phone editDeg"> MBBS </td>
        <td class="span3 hidden-phone editClg"> PMC </td>
        <td class="span3 hidden-phone editYear"> 2010-2014 </td>
        <td class="span3 hidden-phone editCountry"> Pakistan </td>
        <td><button class="span4 EduEdit" >Edit</button><button class="span4 EduDel">Delete</button></td>                                           

    </tr>
 </table>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '.EduEdit', function(){
            var tr = $(this).closest('.eduEditRow');
        var eduId = tr.find('.ids').text();
            var eduDeg = tr.find('.editDeg').text();
            var eduClg = tr.find('.editClg').text();
            var eduCountry = tr.find('.editCountry').text();
            var eduYear = tr.find('.editYear').text();

            alert(eduid);
            alert(eduDeg);
            alert(eduClg);
            alert(eduCountry);
            alert(eduYear);)});     
   </script>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Open the console, and fix the syntax errors

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 syntax errors

```
$(document).on('click', '.EduEdit', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('.eduEditRow');
    var eduId = tr.find('.ids').text();
    var eduDeg = tr.find('.editDeg').text();
    var eduClg = tr.find('.editClg').text();
    var eduCountry = tr.find('.editCountry').text();
    var eduYear = tr.find('.editYear').text();

    alert(eduId);// eduid here
    alert(eduDeg);
    alert(eduClg);
    alert(eduCountry);
    alert(eduYear); //extra `)` here
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8TNra/)